# Porting app engine JDO app to MySql backend

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have a decent-sized App Engine app using JDO and I would like to port it over to a MySql backend using DataNucleus.  I do not anticipate this will be too difficult.  One thing I am running into trouble with, however, are the primary keys.

App Engine uses a Key class to represent the primary key.  This class is basically a combination of a few strings indicating type and name of the object, plus an optional reference to a parent Key (the entire chain of keys up to the topmost parent make up the complete key).  My key declarations look like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
class Whatever {
  ...
  @PrimaryKey
  private Key key;
  ...
}
```

I am ready to implement my own version of Key (and its associated class KeyFactory) but it looks like I might not actually be able to use it as a real primary key the way you do in App Engine.  I don't see any way to use a custom class like this as a key with plain-vanilla DataNucleus JDO.  Even though the documentation does seem to indicate that DataNucleus creates a key class for each primary key, that key class is usually autogenerated and you don't actually declare that key class as a member of the class you want to store.  Even in the case where you have multiple primary keys, where you actually do define the Primary Key class, you store the constituent parts of the key in the class you want to store:

```
@PersistenceCapable(objectIdClass=PersonPrimaryKey.class)
class Person {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String firstname;
  @PrimaryKey
  private String lastname;
  // You can't do this:
  // private PersonPrimaryKey;
  ...
}
class PersonPrimaryKey {
  private String firstname; // has to match above
  private String lastname; // has to match above
  ... // etc other methods
}
```

Compound keys are actually the closest thing to what App Engine has but ultimately I can't see how they would solve my problem either because they have similar restrictions.

Any thoughts, SO?  In addition to the Key object being used in PrimaryKeys I've got tons of places where objects store keys for other types of objects (foreign keys), plus Keys being used elsewhere in query lookups, it's all over the codebase.  If I have to work around this I'll have to implement my own version of Key to use as a reference class, and then put in some extra rigging to translate the Key class to/from a String for use as an actual JDO primary key.  I'd rather not do that because it seems messy but I can't figure out how to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used "Key" for relations (i.e bastardised your model to fit in with those GAE datastore limitations) then you won't be able to run it directly against an RDBMS (if you expect that to equate to a relation and FK in the RDBMS). Those would need changing to a real object reference of the related object.

As for the PK of the class(es) I remember someone referring to an IBM video from 2009 when GAE was launched of them taking a GAE "app" (with Key as primary key field etc) and with the help of some small jar containing the Key class etc, making it runnable against an RDBMS; not see it for some time, maybe on YouTube? Alternatively you could maybe provide a DataNucleus "TypeConverter" for the Key type and see if that will work?